# "echo -e" does not display trailing \n?

Tags: bash, echo

I'm trying to debug why `echo -e` behaves so weirdly on MacOS/Linux that it does not print the trailing '\n'. Is it how `echo` command works?

SCRIPT

```
#!/bin/bash -e

myVar='AA\nBB\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n'

echo ">${myVar}<"

myVar="$(echo -e "${myVar}")"

echo ">${myVar}<"
```

RESULT :

```
>AA\nBB\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<
>AA
BB<
```

Comment: **It's not `echo`.** [_Command substitution_ (`$(command)` or backticks) removes trailing newlines.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) Compare https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17747/why-does-shell-command-substitution-gobble-up-a-trailing-newline- and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17732/where-has-the-trailing-newline-char-gone-from-my-command-substitution

Comment: Please also read [why-is-printf-better-than-echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).